# Sorting an ArrayList<Color> based on RGB

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, colors, rgb

i'm having trouble trying to sort an `ArrayList`of `Color`.

I'm retrieving all the colors from this image 
[imgRed.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nj6b0.jpg)
The code i'm using:

```java
    public static ArrayList<Color> getColors(BufferedImage img){
        int height = img.getHeight();
        int width = img.getWidth();
        boolean found = false;
        ArrayList<Color> List = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int x=0;x<width;x++) {
            for(int y=0;y<height;y++) {
                found = false;
                Color color = new Color(img.getRGB(x, y));
                for(Color c : List) {
                    if(color.getRGB()<c.getRGB()+100 && color.getRGB()>c.getRGB()-100) {
                        found=true;
                    }
                }
                if(!found) {
                    List.add(color);
                }
            }
        }
        return List;
    }
```

After i've collected all the colors, i sort them:

```java
    Collections.sort(Colors, Comparator.comparing(Color::getRed)
            .thenComparing(Color::getGreen)
            .thenComparing(Color::getBlue));
```

Subsequently i create a new image containing all the colors sorted:

```java
    public static void createImage(ArrayList<Color> Colors) {
         int width=500;
            int height=Colors.size()*10;
            BufferedImage b_img =  new BufferedImage(width,height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB); 
            Graphics2D  graphics = b_img.createGraphics();
            int partialHeight = 0;
            int amount = Colors.size();
            for(Color c : Colors) {
                System.out.println("Colors remaining: "+amount);
                graphics.setPaint ( c );
                graphics.fillRect ( 0, partialHeight, b_img.getWidth(), partialHeight+10 );
                partialHeight = partialHeight + 10;
                amount--;
            }
            File outFile = new File("C:/test/img/out/testColor/outputRed4.png");
            try {
                ImageIO.write(b_img, "png", outFile);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

This function produces this image: [outputRed.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdC6N.png)

As you can see, the colors are not really sorted. This is because (i think) colors are sorted basing its numeric value (Red, Green, Blue) and because the RGB numeric value isn't ordered by our perspective.
I remember that the image produced hasn't a color twice so all the color in that image are different.

My question is:

**How can i order all the colors following all the shades of each color without having such a jagged result?**

Thanks to all

Comment: Check whether the `Color` class has a `compareTo(Color other)` method and paste it, if possible. :)

Comment: There is no ordering of colors

Comment: Only if you define it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are encountering comes from the fact that you are taking 3-dimensional data (red values, green values, blue values) and trying to order them in 1 dimension (a `List` with only an `index` parameter).

The output you are receiving is most likely exactly what you should expect if you sort first, by the red value of a colour, and then by the green, and then blue. Remember, this method only compares the green value to sort colours with identical red values, and similarly only compares the blue value to sort colours with identical red **and** blue values.

Perhaps the reason it looks "jagged" is because of the suddenly changing intensity. Given that the input image is pretty much entirely shades of red at different intensities, it might be worth using `Comparator.comparing(Color::getTotal)` where `getTotal()` is defined as:

```
int getTotal() {
    return getGreen() + getBlue() + getRed();
}
```

This will sort by intensity (i.e. brightness), and will make the image look less "jagged", but on images with more than just red, the colours will not be in "colour order" or "rainbow order".

Again, this is an issue of trying to map 3-d data into a 1-d space. Compromises will always have to be made.